# How to Execute a Command Line script on a VM Instance When Updating a Deployment Manager Deployment

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

I currently have this configuration in my `vm.yaml` file, which sets up a vm instance that allows http requests and serves a custom `Hello World!` page, as specified in the `startup-scripts` section:

```
resources:
- type: compute.v1.instance
  name: quickstart-deployment-vm
  properties:
    zone: us-central1-f
    machineType: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my_project/zones/us-central1-f/machineTypes/f1-micro
    disks:
      ...
    networkInterfaces:
      ...
    tags:
        items: ["http"]

    metadata:
      items:
      - key: startup-script
        value: |
          #!/bin/bash
          apt-get update
          apt-get install -y apache2
          echo '<!doctype html><html><body><h1>Hello World!</h1></body></html>' | sudo tee /var/www/html/index.html

- type: compute.v1.firewall
  name: tcp-firewall-rule
  properties:
    targetTags: ["http"]
    network: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my_project/global/networks/default
    sourceRanges: ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    targetTags: ["http","http-server"]
    allowed:
     - IPProtocol: TCP
       ports: ["80"]
```

After running `gcloud deployment-manager deployments create vm-deploy --config vm.yaml`, I get the expected `Hello World!` response when accessing the vm's external ip. However, I now want to update this deployment to change the content of the response, let's say to `What's up, everyone!` However, it seems like I cannot do this simply by changing what is in the `startup-scripts` section. I tried putting this in a `vm-update.yaml` file:

```
resources:
- type: compute.v1.instance
  name: quickstart-deployment-vm
  properties:
    ...
    metadata:
      items:
      - key: startup-script
        value: |
          #!/bin/bash
          apt-get update
          apt-get install -y apache2
          echo '<!doctype html><html><body><h1>What's up, everyone!</h1></body></html>' | sudo tee /var/www/html/index.html

- type: compute.v1.firewall
  name: tcp-firewall-rule
  properties:
    ...
```

And ran `gcloud deployment-manager deployments update vm-deploy --config vm-update.yaml`. However, the response and the `index.html` file have not changed, and they are still `Hello World!`. I'm guessing this is because the `startup-script` is only executed upon instance creation, but not upon instance update. Does anyone know how I can execute a script on my vm with deployment manager, when I'm updating the vm?

Comment: Did you restart your VM after running an `update` command ? Check after running the command if your startup-script is in place.

Comment: I didn't. After I restarted the VM, I saw the new ```index.html``` file in place. Do you know if there is a way to update the ```index.html``` just in Deployment Manager, without manually restarting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One 'hack' I found was I could change the `machineType` of the VM in `vm-update.yaml`, which I believe forces the VM to be rebooted/reinitialized, and run the `startup-script`.

Answer (score 0):

To use Deployment Manager to update `index.html` (in a running server) and make the changes "live" just add a line `service apache2 reload` in your update `yaml` file just after the `echo` part; like so:

```
    metadata:
      items:
      - key: startup-script
        value: |
          #!/bin/bash
          apt-get update
          apt-get install -y apache2
          echo '<!doctype html><html><body><h1>What's up, everyone!</h1></body></html>' | sudo tee /var/www/html/index.html
          service apache2 reload
```

This will reload the service (more secure than `restart`) and serve the new `index.html` file.

Or you can change the added line to `reboot -n` but only when it's convinient for you. Restarting only the service is much quicker.

Comment: Hi, I tried this and it still seems to not work. When I check ```index.html```, it is not updated, again I think because the ```startup-script``` is only run when the vm is rebooted or initialized. You can see my answer for an indirect way I got it to work.